# Rip but maintain vertices

Tags: modeling, mesh

I don't know if I'm explaining exactly right so any reccomendations for title improvements is welcome

[image]

Is there any shortcut that I can drag out a new vertice like this, but still maintain the old one?

[image]

Answer (score 12):

You're probably looking for a ***Rip Fill*** option. Select the vertex, then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (or type it via <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> menu). Then you can slide the vertex (by taping the <kbd>G</kbd> button twice) and delete the unnecessary edges using the *Edge Dissolve* option (<kbd>X</kbd>).
[image]

Comment: Excellent, I also didn't know about that feature :) Thanks

Comment: Jan, I also didn't know about this feature until now :). I love how the BSE force you to find and learn the new solutions. Greetings from Poland neighbour!

Comment: Exactly! Helping others while learning new things... two birds with one stone  :) We are all neighbors in the world of internet but greetings to you too! :)

Answer (score 7):

The **Rip Fill** feature in the answer by Paul is the one you want.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/91703/13643

These are just **alternative methods** you can try:

Connect those 2 vertices and press <kbd>J</kbd> to *Vertex Connect Path*, then select the faces with extra edges and use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to execute *Tris to Quads* so it dissolves the unnecessary edges.

[image]

Connect those 2 vertices using *Knife Tool* <kbd>K</kbd> and then use *Tris to Quads* <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> as in the previous method:

[image]

Or you can select 2 vertices and make a new vertex between them by <kbd>W</kbd> > *Subdivide* and turn on *Quad/Tri mode*. Then again, select the faces and use *Tris to Quads* <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> (or just use this at the very end on the whole model).

[image]

Comment: I wasn't using knife tool at all before, I'll certainly give it a try, thanks

Comment: I added another method where you can use J key (Vertex Connect Path), it is even quicker than using Knife tool.