# vertex slide within face

Tags: modeling, vertices

I recently discovered *vertex slide* and *edge slide* which are very useful. Now I'm in a similar situation, but I want to move a vertex such that it stays within the plane of a face. Is there a similar way to do this?

(What I am trying to do is modelling the [Szilassi polyhedron](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/72/Szilassi_polyhedron.gif), where you could see the usefulness of such a tool.)

Comment: Related? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91700/rip-but-maintain-vertices

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Comment: @RyanStout Unfortunately not. I also found out that this could only work with triangular faces, as soon as you have four vertices you do not necessarily have a planar face anymore.

Comment: @RyanStout There is an answer now:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move a vertex along the normal of the associated face. This doesn't ensure that the face was planar in the first place.

1. Switch to **Normal** orientation mode.
2. Select a Face in face mode.
3. Scale its Z normal to 0 in face mode. <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

At this point nothing should have changed. If anything changed your face was not planar to begin with.

1. Make sure all vertices of the face only belong to a single face by ripping them. <kbd>V</kbd>
2. Move them along the face normal. <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>

[image: ripping and moving along normal]

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 2):

You can duplicate your object and set the snap tool to face. When you move the vertex in edit mode it will snap to the face of your duplicated object.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by the vertex “surface slide” tool from MACHIN3tools for Blender 2.79. Now not work in Blender 2.80: 
https://github.com/machin3io/MACHIN3tools/branches
https://blenderartists.org/t/machin3tools/1135716/199