# How to model the Szilassi polyhedron?

Tags: modeling, vertices

I'm trying to model the [Szilassi polyhedron](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/72/Szilassi_polyhedron.gif). (Actually I'm trying to do something else but this is probably the simplest case I could find.)

The problem here is that we have to have multiple vertices within the planes of the faces, that should line up with other planes. A while ago I asked whether it is possible to [slide a vertex within a face](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93566/vertex-slide-within-face) but did not find a satisfactory solution.

So how else would you go about modelling such a polyhedron?

The exact dimensions are not important at all, but the points that are within one plane should remain coplanar in the model.

Comment: It is a bit cumbersome and uncomfortable to use but you could "draw" each face using a 2D bezier curve object, that would guarantee planar faces and that the vertex only move in local XY plane, or least use 2D bezier curves as guides to snap your actual mesh to.

Comment: I did it using a couple of bool operations. Do you want me to post the steps? [It's not some magic knowledge though.] [And I rendered you a better gif.](https://imgur.com/a/eIKZbMK)